# get fifth value from variable using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a value which can be any of the following:

- `2013 Hyundai Elantra Silver 5NPDH4AE4DH174965`
- `2013 Hyundai Sonata White 5NPEB4AC1 DH684081`
- `2013 Kia Forte White KNAFU4A20D56800 11`

This value is stored in the variable called `$getVechileInfo["getVechileInfo"]`

Now I want to get `5NPDH4AE4DH174965` from first one, `5NPEB4AC1 DH684081` from second one and `KNAFU4A20D56800 11` from third one.

So how could I do that with PHP or any PHP function?

Comment: use `explode($value, " ", 4)`, then take 4th element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this do?

```
    $info = $getVechileInfo["getVechileInfo"];
    $info = explode(" ",$info);
    array_splice($info,0,4);
    $info = implode(" ",$info);
```

Clarification - It explodes your string into an array, and then splices out the first 4 segments, then joins them back together, this should give you the last parts of the array as a string.

Comment: Btw that won't work if he has `2014 Jeep Grand Cherokee White 5NPEB4AC1 DH684081`

Comment: your code give me this `2013 Hyundai Elantra Silver` when I `echo $info;`, I need fifth value not this `2013 Hyundai Elantra Silver` value fifth is `5NPDH4AE4DH174965`, `5NPEB4AC1 DH684081` and `KNAFU4A20D56800 11`.

Comment: Want to give it a go now?

Comment: I just change this `$info = array_splice($info,0,4);` into this `$info = array_splice($info,4,4);` and it is working now. Let me check all my values first.

Comment: Just to clarify @user3833682 the value you're changing there is the offset, either your method of giving it an offset of 4 or my way of splicing out the first 4 works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check strpos() function. Examples here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

EDIT:

```
  $info = $getVechileInfo["getVechileInfo"];
   $5th_element = explode(" ",$info);
  echo $5th_element[4];
```

Should work

Comment: User neomm I already try `strpos()` but this function not fulfill my requirement.

Comment: So try use strpos() and  user: @Duenna tip. Or use str_replace() to replace " " to "," and use str_getcsv to get array. If your string is always on 5th possition, it should work